# How to Create side bar menu with navigation in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and working on a web app, I want side bar menu similar to any website. I search a lot but some are using `getx` for navigation and some are using `navigationrail` 
I don't want to use both of these and neither any other package. Is it possible to create simple side menu bar without using these.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What navigation strategy are you using? Declarative or imperative? Are you using third party packages such as [GoRouter](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package [easy_sidemenu](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_sidemenu) just define a PageController and you're ready to go